# How do I update data without reloading mongodb expressjs react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

So I want to update my data on the client-side without reloading, But I don't know how to.

here is my front end code

```
const handleStockUp = event => {
       const oldQuantity = item.quantity;
       const newQuantity = event.target.quantity.value;
       const quantity = Number(oldQuantity) + Number(newQuantity);
          console.log(quantity)
            event.preventDefault()
            const updatedQuantity = { quantity };
            const url = `http://localhost:5000/item/${itemId}`;
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(updatedQuantity)
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    event.target.reset();
                })
        }
    
    <form onSubmit={handleStockUp}>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" name="stock" >StockUp</button>
    </form>
```

So You Like put a number in the input field then press the button it should update the quantity but you have to reload to check it. and the backend Code

```
app.put('/item/:id', async (req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const updatedQuantity = req.body;
        const filter = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
        const options = { upsert: true };
        const updatedDoc = {
            $set: {
                quantity: updatedQuantity.quantity
            }
        };
        const result = await computerCollection.updateOne(filter, updatedDoc, options);
        res.send(result);
    });
```

Please Tell me if you know how to solve if :)

Comment: You should use a state to store the quantity. Can you post your React component's full code? From your snippet, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add these following code before your handleStockUp function.

```js
 const { id } = useParams();
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState({});   

    useEffect(() => {

        const url = `http://localhost:5000/item/${id}`;

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setQuantity(data));

    }, [quantity, id]); // Make sure you have added dependency here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).